# Mac "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: macos, react-native, gcc, config, configure

When I ran my RN project on xcode10,I got an error:"config.h not found".
So I ran "ios-install-third-party.sh" and "ios-configure-glog.sh" as suggested.but I got another error :"configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables".

I've tried some answers, but didn't work.

I found something in my config.log,but don't know how to fix it:

```
configure:3665: checking for C compiler version
configure:3674: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot  --version >&5
clang: error: no input files
```

Here is my config.log :

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by glog configure 0.3.4, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = JiangJiahao
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 17.7.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 8 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
8 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 401 tasks, 1509 threads, 8 processors
Load average: 1.71, Mach factor: 6.27
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/jiangjiahao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
PATH: /Users/jiangjiahao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin
PATH: /Users/jiangjiahao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /Users/jiangjiahao/.rvm/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2788: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2856: result: /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c
configure:2867: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2922: result: yes
configure:2960: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure:2981: checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip
configure:3011: result: no
configure:3021: checking for strip
configure:3037: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:3048: result: strip
configure:3073: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3112: result: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
configure:3119: checking for gawk
configure:3149: result: no
configure:3119: checking for mawk
configure:3149: result: no
configure:3119: checking for nawk
configure:3149: result: no
configure:3119: checking for awk
configure:3135: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:3146: result: awk
configure:3157: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3179: result: yes
configure:3208: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3225: result: yes
configure:3369: checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc
configure:3396: result: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot 
configure:3665: checking for C compiler version
configure:3674: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot  --version >&5
clang: error: no input files
configure:3685: $? = 1
configure:3674: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot  -v >&5
clang: error: no input files
configure:3685: $? = 1
configure:3674: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot  -V >&5
clang: error: no input files
configure:3685: $? = 1
configure:3674: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot  -qversion >&5
clang: error: no input files
configure:3685: $? = 1
configure:3705: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3727: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot     conftest.c  >&5
clang: error: no input files
configure:3731: $? = 1
configure:3769: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "glog"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glog"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.3.4"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "glog 0.3.4"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "opensource@google.com"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "glog"
| #define VERSION "0.3.4"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3774: error: in `/Users/jiangjiahao/Desktop/work/tapdb-client-rn/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4':
configure:3776: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot '
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot '
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-apple-darwin
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/local/bin/ginstall -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/local/bin/gmkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_CC='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot '
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_STRIP=strip
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='aclocal-1.14'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
AUTOCONF='autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='automake-1.14'
AWK='awk'
CC='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot '
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot '
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DISABLE_RTTI_FALSE=''
DISABLE_RTTI_TRUE=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_FRAME_POINTERS_FALSE=''
ENABLE_FRAME_POINTERS_TRUE=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GCC_FALSE=''
GCC_TRUE=''
GFLAGS_CFLAGS=''
GFLAGS_LIBS=''
GMOCK_CFLAGS=''
GMOCK_CONFIG=''
GMOCK_LIBS=''
GREP=''
GTEST_CFLAGS=''
GTEST_CONFIG=''
GTEST_LIBS=''
HAVE_GMOCK_FALSE=''
HAVE_GMOCK_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIBTOOL_DEPS=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MINGW_CFLAGS=''
MKDIR_P='/usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='glog'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='opensource@google.com'
PACKAGE_NAME='glog'
PACKAGE_STRING='glog 0.3.4'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='glog'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.3.4'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP='strip'
UNWIND_LIBS=''
VERSION='0.3.4'
X86_64_FALSE=''
X86_64_TRUE=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ac_cv___attribute___noinline=''
ac_cv___attribute___noreturn=''
ac_cv___attribute___printf_4_5=''
ac_cv_cxx_using_operator=''
ac_cv_have___builtin_expect=''
ac_cv_have___uint16=''
ac_cv_have_inttypes_h=''
ac_cv_have_libgflags=''
ac_cv_have_stdint_h=''
ac_cv_have_systypes_h=''
ac_cv_have_u_int16_t=''
ac_cv_have_uint16_t=''
ac_cv_have_unistd_h=''
ac_google_end_namespace=''
ac_google_namespace=''
ac_google_start_namespace=''
acx_pthread_config=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='arm-apple-darwin'
host_alias='arm-apple-darwin'
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /Users/jiangjiahao/Desktop/work/tapdb-client-rn/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "glog"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glog"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.3.4"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "glog 0.3.4"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "opensource@google.com"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "glog"
#define VERSION "0.3.4"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: What's an "RN" project? Why are you running `ios-` commands on a Mac - `ios` is the operating system for iPhones/iPads not Macs? Macs use `macOS`. Why is your compiler compiling for `ARM` - that is the architecture of iPhones/iPads?

Comment: Where did you download this project from?

Comment: I'm developing an iOS app using react-native.

Comment: Please consider adding the `react-native` tag then.

Comment: Added.Thansk :)